# Wrapping types with alignment requirements

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, template, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2013 still doesn't support the `alignas` keyword in C++11. This causes some problems with alignment of types in various situations. Thankfully the compiler will generate an error when it can't guarantee the alignment or at least give a warning.

To solve these errors and warnings I'm implementing a wrapper type that will wrap another type with some alignment restriction regardless of how the wrapper is aligned. Consider two wrapper objects `A` and `B` that themselves have arbitrary alignment. Let the wrapped datum be `a` and `b` respectively. Then `A=B` will assign `a=b` while still keeping `a` aligned regardless of how `B` was aligned because `b` in itself is aligned.

I'm looking for a review on the code on the account of syntax and possible weaknesses in the design and implementation.

```
template< typename T, std::size_t Align = 16>
class aligned_wrapper{
public:
    typedef T value_type;

    template<typename... Args>
    aligned_wrapper(Args&&... args){
        std::size_t space = sizeof(m_storage);
        auto raw_ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&m_storage);
        auto ptr = std::align(Align, sizeof(T), raw_ptr, space);
        new (ptr)T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        m_object = reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);
    }

    ~aligned_wrapper(){
        get().~T();
    }

    aligned_wrapper& operator = (const aligned_wrapper& that){
        get() = that.get();
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename U>
    aligned_wrapper(const aligned_wrapper<U>& that)
        : aligned_wrapper(that.get())
    {}

    template<typename U>
    aligned_wrapper(aligned_wrapper<U>&& that)
        : aligned_wrapper(std::move(that.get()))
    {}

    inline T& get(){ return *m_object; }
    inline const T& get() const { return *m_object; }

    void swap(aligned_wrapper& that){
        using std::swap;
        swap(get(), that.get());
    }

    friend void swap(aligned_wrapper& lhs, aligned_wrapper& rhs){
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }
private:
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T) + Align - 1, 1> m_storage;
    T* m_object{ nullptr };
};
```

Although it may look a bit funky, one of the key ideas is that once the `aligned_wrapper` is constructed, `m_object` will never change for that instance as the address of `this` will not change, this guarantees alignment. In other words, not assigning `m_object` in the assignment operator is intentional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The class is missing a copy constructor and a move constructor. These can *never* be created by instantiating a template. Right now, the compiler will generate a defaulted copy constructor for you (and no move constructor, because you have a user-defined destructor). Since you obviously don't want that, you have to define the copy (and probably move as well) constructor yourself.
2. You're also missing a move assignment operator which you should probably add. Otherwise, your class wouldn't be fully usable with move-only types.
3. Your code is missing comments (there aren't *any*). You even had to explain an invariant in the question:

   > ... once the `aligned_wrapper` is constructed, `m_object` will never change for that instance as the address of `this` will not change, this guarantees alignment. In other words, not assigning `m_object` in the assignment operator is intentional.

   This type of information *must* go into comments. The next maintainer (which can be you in 6 moths' time) will need knowledge like this to understand the code.
4. You should add `noexcept` specifications to your functions. They affect efficiency of some operations (like storing in a `std::vector`), and since this is a very generic class, you should not limit its use in any way. An example for the assignment operator would be:

   ```
   aligned_wrapper& operator = (const aligned_wrapper& that) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<T>::value) {
       get() = that.get();
       return *this;
   }
   ```
5. It would probably be a good idea to introduce a way to query `Align` out of an `aligned_wrapper` object, e.g.

   ```
   static const std::size_t alignment = Align;
   ```
6. You don't need `reinterpret_cast` to convert an object pointer to `void*`, a `static_cast` is sufficient for that. Don't use stronger casts than necessary.
7. You can simplify the assignment to `m_object` and make it more obvious by assigning the result of the placement-new into it:

   ```
   m_object = new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   ```
8. `16` looks like a rather arbitrary number for the default template argument for `Align` (it's actually a magic number). There is even no guarantee that 16 is a valid alignment value. I would probably choose something less arbitrary such as `sizeof(void*)`.
9. There is no reason to use `std::aligned_storage` for the type of `m_storage`. You don't actually care about alignment of `m_storage` at all (which is emphasised by you passing `1` to its `Align` parameter). All you need is a buffer of suitable size, and for this `usigned char[sizeof(T) + Align -1]` (or a `std::array`) would work just as well.

   As a side note, be aware that `std::aligned_storage_t` was only introduced in C++14. Visual Studio 2013 supports some C++14 bits, but using it makes your code non-C++11-compliant.
10. You might want to swap the order of the data members, it might prevent need for padding between an oddly-sized `m_storage` and aligned `m_object`.
11. You might consider overloading the pointer operators `*` and `->` for your class as syntactic sugar for `get()`, it simplifies usage. Other generic classes which store a single object sometimes do so as well; an example is [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_operator_asterisk).